# Print certain part of the page

Tags: php, css

Based on the coding "How to only print this part in the coding".

```
echo'<br/><br/>Token number : '.$row3['Token_ID'].'<br/>Patient Name : '.$row3['Name'].'<br/>Doctor Name: '.$row3['Doctor_Name'].'<br/>Room Number: '.$row3['Room_Number'].'<br/>';
```

Here's the full coding:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Clinic Management System </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<?php
include ('./includess/header2.html');

?>
<body>
<center><h2><b>Token Registration</b></h2></center>
<form action ='Token_Registration.php' method = "POST">
<div id="frm"><legend>Token information :</legend>

<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for IC...."/>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Search"/>

<?php

$page_title = 'Register';


if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
  $nic = $_POST['search'];
  require_once ('mysql_connect.php');
  $query1 = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE IC_Number = '$nic'";
  $result1 = @mysql_query($query1);
  $num1 = @mysql_num_rows($result1);      


if ($num1 >0)
  {
    while($row1 = @mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      $_SESSION['paid'] = $row1['ID'];
  echo
  '<br/><br/>Name : '.$row1['Name'].'<br/> Patient ID :'.$row1['ID'].'<br/>';

}

   }    
 else 
 {
 echo '<br/><font color="red"> Wrong IC number or Person does not exist       </font>';
  } 
 } 


?>

<p><b>Doctor Name :</b> <input type ="text" name = "Doctor_Name" /></p>
<p><b>Room Number :</b> <input type ="text" name = "Room_Number" /></p>
<div align ="left"><input type = "submit" name = "submit"  value = "Register"     /><p><input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="Print Here"/></div>

<?php 

$page_title = 'Register';
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$paid = $_SESSION['paid'];
/*$pname = $_SESSION['pname'];*/            
require_once ('mysql_connect.php');

$rnum = $_POST['Room_Number'];
$dname = $_POST['Doctor_Name'];
/*$query2 = "INSERT INTO token (Patient_ID, Doctor_Name, Patient_Name) VALUES ('$paid', '$dname', '$pname' ) "; */
$query2 = "INSERT INTO token (Patient_ID, Room_Number, Doctor_Name) VALUES ('$paid','$rnum', '$dname') ";
$result2 = @mysql_query($query2);  

 if ($result2)
 {

    /*$query3 = "SELECT * FROM patients ,token WHERE ((patients.ID = token.Patient_ID AND token.Patient_ID = '$paid') AND (patients.Name = token.Patient_Name AND token.Patient_Name = '$pname'))"; */
        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM patients ,token WHERE patients.ID = token.Patient_ID AND token.Patient_ID = '$paid'";
    $result3 = @mysql_query($query3);
    $num3 = @mysql_num_rows($result3);      

          if ($num3 >0)
            {
              while($row3 = @mysql_fetch_array($result3, MYSQL_ASSOC))
              {
                echo'<br/><br/>Token number : '.$row3['Token_ID'].'<br/>Patient Name : '.$row3['Name'].'<br/>Doctor Name: '.$row3['Doctor_Name'].'<br/>Room Number: '.$row3['Room_Number'].'<br/>';
                 }
            }

           else {
           echo "Error";
           }
   }
}


  ?>    
  </form>
  </div>

  <?php 
  include ('./includes/footer.html'); 
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the content you want to print in a `<div id="printPortion">`

you can use a button with a click function to trigger the print and then use the below code to print only the content of the div.

You can print the content that you need using javascript

```
var restorePage = document.body.innerHTML;
var printPortion = document.getElementById('printPortion').innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printPortion;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = restorePage;
```

Comment: Sorry but can you please explain where am I supposed to wrap the content <div id="printPortion">

Comment: echo'<div class="printPortion"><br/><br/>Token number : '.$row3['Token_ID'].'<br/>Patient Name : '.$row3['Name'].'<br/>Doctor Name: '.$row3['Doctor_Name'].'<br/>Room Number: '.$row3['Room_Number'].'<br/></div>';

Comment: Sorry again. But it still print the whole screen. It didn't worked. :(